# How to make grid-items take only remaining space from rows?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make grid-item number 2, 3, 4 squeeze to top, It shouldn't start from its natural grid-lines. I want to remove horizontal extra space between grid-item (2-3) and grid-item 3-4. How can I achieve this?

**Grid Item 1 can be of any height. It is dynamic.**

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.container>div {
  background-color: teal;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.item1 {
  grid-row: 1/4;
  height: 500px;
}

.item2,
.item3,
.item4 {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to think about grids are abstractional layers and not fixed structures. This way you freely place your divs into the grid blocks and not BE the grid blocks.

Following this pattern, defining a grid of 8 rows, for example, and telling your divs to occupy "x" rows could do the trick. Feel free to play with the rows number and spans to better suit your needs. :)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.container>div {
  background-color: teal;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.item1 {
  grid-row: 1/8;
  height: 500px;
}

.item2,
.item3,
.item4 {
  grid-row: span 2;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
</div>
```

This is the sketch of the idea:
[image]

Comment: Excuse me for not being so clear, what if we don't know the height of **grid-item 1**, It can be of any height

Comment: That also worked and you explain it briefly. +1

Answer (score 2):

The simplest somlution would be to add another row that can expand.

```
.item1 {
  grid-row: 1/5;
  height: 500px;
}
```

`grid-row: 1/5` means that the grid will have 4 rows. This allows 3 items to flow to the top on the right side, and the forth row can expand as needed.

Comment: Excuse me for not being so clear, what if we don't know the height of grid-item 1, It can be of any height

Comment: Do you know the total number of items in the grid?

Comment: Total number of items will always remain same i.e. 4 as in example shown above

Comment: In that case my solution would work, because the last row would just expand. Unless the height of item 1 is shorter than the height of item 2-4 combined. In that case you should put items 2-4 in a separate div.

Comment: Yup it worked. It would be great if you could explain it briefly.

Comment: I'm gonna accept the **Анна** answer. Since she explained it briefly and answered first. Thanks for helping me...